Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime Agent Offline Issue
I have successfully created a Self-Hosted Runtime agent to my On-Premise SQL DB from my Azure Data Factory.
The integration runtime agent shows that it has successfully established a connection to ADF

However, the integrationruntime is showing as down/offline in ADF.

Can someone let me know how to reactivate it? Also, let me know why it went offline?

Once try to refresh the IR

On your self-hosted, go to the diagnostic tab and check the logs to see if it was offline and why
